# Interpolating data in R

Tags: r, gaussian, interpolation

Let's suppose I have a 3 by 5 matrix in R:

```
4  5  5  6  8
3  4  4  5  6
2  3  3  3  4
```

I would like to interpolate in between these values to create a matrix of size 15 by 25. I would also like to specify if the interpolation is linear, gaussian, etc. How can I do this?

For example, if I have a small matrix like this

```
2 3
1 3
```

and I want it to become 3 by 3, then it might look like

```
  2    2.5   3
  1.5  2.2   3
  1    2     3
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Please provide sample output.

Comment: this post may be of some help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093455/3d-geometry-how-to-interpolate-a-matrix

Comment: @Arun that seems useful although there must be a built in function in R to do this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
app <- function(x, n) approx(x, n=n)$y # Or whatever interpolation that you want

apply(t(apply(x, 1, function(x) app(x, nc))), 2, function(x) app(x, nr))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  2.0 2.50    3
[2,]  1.5 2.25    3
[3,]  1.0 2.00    3
```

Comment: To followup on my comments at my answer: if I'm reading this code correctly, setting `nc` and `nr` to the number of cols/rows you want for the output matrix will allow arbitrary asymmetric expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I wrote a similar toy, except I never got around to defining the interpolation function.  There's also `raster::disaggregate` .

```
zexpand<-function(inarray, fact=2, interp=FALSE,  ...)  {
# do same analysis of fact to allow one or two values, fact >=1 required, etc.
fact<-as.integer(round(fact))
switch(as.character(length(fact)),
            '1' = xfact<-yfact<-fact,
            '2'= {xfact<-fact[1]; yfact<-fact[2]},
            {xfact<-fact[1]; yfact<-fact[2];warning(' fact is too long. First two values used.')})
if (xfact < 1) { stop('fact[1] must be > 0') } 
if (yfact < 1) { stop('fact[2] must be > 0') }
bigtmp <- matrix(rep(t(inarray), each=xfact), nrow(inarray), ncol(inarray)*xfact, byr=T)  #does column expansion
bigx <- t(matrix(rep((bigtmp),each=yfact),ncol(bigtmp),nrow(bigtmp)*yfact,byr=T))
# the interpolation would go here. Or use interp.loess on output (won't
# handle complex data). Also, look at fields::Tps which probably does
# a much better job anyway.  Just do separately on Re and Im data
return(invisible(bigx))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How is this different or better than Math Lundberg's answer above?

Comment: @CodeGuy  If I actually put an interpolation function in there (basically replacing the `rep` function which just duplicates rows or columns), it would be doing almost exactly the same thing, except that I allow for different expansions in the column- and row- dimensions.  As Matthew wrote, you can swap in whatever interpolator you want in is code as well.