# interpolate two matrices with Eigen3

Tags: c++, matrix, interpolation, eigen, quaternions

I have two transformation matrices and I want to interpolate between them for an animation.
As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093455/3d-geometry-how-to-interpolate-a-matrix) it is not possible to simply interpolate the single values. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? (I use Eigen3)

My Idea:

```
Eigen::Matrix4f m1; //Transformation Matrix 1
Eigen::Matrix4f m2; //Transformation Matrix 2
Eigen::Quaternion<float> quat1(m1.block<3,3>(0,0)); //This extracts rotation matrix
Eigen::Quaternion<float> quat2(m2.block<3,3>(0,0));
quat1.slerp(t,quat2); //This interpolates

//Now i need a 4x4 Matrix again
Eigen::Matrix3f rot=quat1.toRotationMatrix();
Eigen::Matrix4f newmatrix;
newmatrix.block<3,3>(0,0)=rot;
```

Is there something wrong with my code and is there an easy way to accomplish (rotation) matrix interpolation?

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify this lines

   ```
   Eigen::Quaternion<float> quat3  = quat1.slerp(t,quat2); //This interpolates
   //Now i need a 4x4 Matrix again
   Eigen::Matrix3f rot = quat3.toRotationMatrix();
   ```
2. Also, interpolate linearly translation component (last column of `m1` and `m2`)
3. Be sure, that `m1` and `m2` are Euclidean transformations, NOT projective.